# Does session timeout renewal after the last request made or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

This could be a very basic and easier question but I want to learn. 
As I understand, default ASP.NET Session timesout after 20 mins. So, what happens if the user postbacks to the server in 15th min? will the session of the user be 5 more minutes or will be 20  more minutes from the time of postback(15+20=35mins from Start)? This renewal of session happens everytime server is pinged by user!

If I am right, Session timeout is the period after which ASP.NET can terminate the user session if it hears nothing, meaning no postback. This made me think of the above question.

Answer (score 4):

The session timeout uses a **sliding expiration** - that is, as you described, the session timeout resets after each request.

If the client remains idle for the timeout period, the session will then expire.

Reference:[Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Quote:

> Specifies the number of minutes a session can be **idle** before it is
>   abandoned. The timeout attribute cannot be set to a value that is
>   greater than 525,601 minutes (1 year) for the in-process and
>   state-server modes.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right. Session expires 20 mins after the last request made.

Comment: It would be complete if you cite your source